# Trying to load QML file in a PyQt6 project aborts with memory leak

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt6

I am trying to load another qml from another python file triggered by a websocket event.

I have this in `main.py`:

```
QQuickWindow.setSceneGraphBackend('software')

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
# app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(''))

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

login = Login(app, engine)
websocket = Websocket(app, engine)

engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('login', login)
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('websocket', websocket)
app.aboutToQuit.connect(exiting)
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('./UI/login.qml')

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This loads up fine. When the user logged in, it loads up the main.qml no problem (which is called inside login.py)

My problem comes when I want to load another QML based on an outside event from websocket. I  already gave the class the app and engine instance. It aborts with memory leak everytime.

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

When I load with `engine.load("websocket.qml")` inside `main.py` after `engine.load('./UI/login.qml')` it works. It loads up in a new window.

But if I try in another class which is in another file, it fails. Tried to fix with numerous things but fails everytime.

In my Websocket class the engine instance is seems okay and the qml file exists.

```
print(type(self.engine)) # returns the instance
print(os.path.isfile('anotherqml.qml')) # prints out True
```

Any idea?

Comment: How are you actually loading the other QML? You're not trying to use threading, are you?

Comment: Actually... I don't know. I think the websocket package I'm using is maybe use it? When I tried to run as a script rathen than module, it gave me an error saying RuntimeError: cannot join current thread. When I ran as a module, it runs fine. I will try to skip the websocket package tomorrow. Until then, can you elaborate what is the downfall using threading in this situation?

Comment: UI elements are not thread-safe, and can only be created in the main thread. The only way thread-safe way to communicate between threads in Qt (and allow interacting with the UI, including creating new UI elements) is by using signals.

Comment: It was using threading. I am now emitting the data we receive through pyqtSignal() and connecting to it from the main thread and now it loads up the new qml fine. Thanks!